# user agent client hintが一部の人が取れない

Tags: php

user agentがこれから簡略化されることで、新しくuser agent client hintから端末名などとりだしているのですが、一部の人の情報が取り出せなくて困っています

headerでuachをリクエストして
apache_request_headersで情報を取り出しています

端末がわとかで拒否する設定や取り出せないこととかあるのでしょうか？
phpで処理をおこなっています

Comment: 「一部の人」と問題ない他の人との違いは？ ブラウザによっては対応してないと言うこともありそうです。

Answer (score 1):

> 一部の人の情報が取り出せなくて困っています

「一部の人」と問題ない他の人との違いが何だか分かりませんが・・・

User-Agent Client Hints は現時点では実験的な機能であり、対応ブラウザも Edge, Chrome, Opera に限られているそうです。そのせいでは？

ユーザーエージェントクライアントヒント API
https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/User-Agent_Client_Hints_API

あと、「一部の人」以外は取得できているようなので違うかもしれませんが、ブラウザからの最初の要求にはバージョン情報は含まれず、次の要求からになるということは理解されていますか？

そこが問題ならば、Accept-CH と一緒に Critical-CH ヘッダーを応答ヘッダに含めてクライアント（ブラウザ）に送るという方法を考えてみてください。そうすると、ブラウザは最初の応答を受けた後、直ちに再度要求を出し、その要求ヘッダには Critical-CH ヘッダーに指定された情報を含めて送信してくれます。

詳しい説明は以下の記事に書きましたので、興味があれば読んでください。

User-Agent Client Hints
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2023/04/21/user-agent-client-hints.aspx